# How to read data from optical drive in raw mode 2

Tags: linux, drivers, block-device, data-cd

I am trying to use the existing Linux driver system to effectively dump the data of CDROMs.

As an example, if I pop in a "normal" CDROM disc of software and run the command

```
cat /dev/sr0
```

then the output is a bunch of raw data from the disc - which is great.

However, some other types of CDs result in IO errors after just a little data.

Some research has led me to understand that data is being read by default in "Mode 1". (Info on format/structure can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM#CD-ROM_format)

For discs with data in Mode 2, what would it take to be able to read them? Are there any driver or kernel settings to change the mode?

Note: There are other programs to accomplish this such as cdrdao, but my question is for how to do it natively.

Update 1: Some potential leads:

- High level explanation of cdrom driver architecture: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/sr.html
- Potentially useful module parameter which happens to be disabled by default: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=xa_test (turning it on does not solve the problem though)

Comment: It seems XA mode have at least 2 partitions. http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-89769.html

Comment: Have you tried dd if=/dev/sr0 and see if it results in IO errors as well

Comment: There used to be a v2.4-v2.6 kernel module [CDfs](http://users.elis.ugent.be/~mronsse/cdfs/), that could mount both disk sessions of an XA CD.  Running it would require either booting an  old linux distro, or perhaps running an old distro from an emulator.

Comment: The mode of each sector is defined in the seventeenth byte. Enabling the XA check will only cause Linux to read that byte and decide it's not a mode2/XA sector. (The actual data mode 2 work is in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/sr_read_cd; it's usually called such that the cd-drive determines the data mode.)